# Kubernetes pod Ephemeral storage hosting a fast api gradually increasing over time

Tags: python, kubernetes, ephemeral-storage

I built a FastAPI on Kubernetes and noticed my pod Ephemeral storage is gradually increasing over time.

Pod Empheral Image:

[image: Pod Empheral Image]

What will be the factors causing this ?
Log file ? A lot of print statements? A lot of logging ?

[Kubernetes console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmpk2.png)

Can anyone advise me?